# Insert selected data to multiple tables in other database

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-insert

I need to select some columns from 4 tables in WordPress database
after that I want to insert selected data into 2 tables in other database

With this query I selected data successfully

```
SELECT
  B.order_item_id AS id,
  A.ID AS order_id,
  A.post_modified_gmt AS date_modified,
  A.post_status AS status,
  B.order_item_name AS product_name,
  E.guid AS product_image,
  F.meta_value AS qty,
  G.meta_value AS sku,
  H.num_items_sold AS total_items

FROM wp_posts A

  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items B
    ON A.ID = B.order_id
    
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta C
    ON B.order_item_id = C.order_item_id

  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta F
    ON B.order_item_id = F.order_item_id AND F.meta_key = ('_qty')
    
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta D
    ON C.meta_value = D.post_id

  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta G
    ON C.meta_value = G.post_id AND G.meta_key = ('_sku')       
    
  INNER JOIN wp_posts E
    ON D.meta_value = E.ID
    
  INNER JOIN wp_wc_order_stats H
    ON B.order_id = H.order_id
    
WHERE A.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND A.post_status = 'wc-processing'
AND C.meta_key IN ('_product_id')
AND D.meta_key IN ('_thumbnail_id')
AND F.meta_key IN ('_qty')
AND G.meta_key IN ('_sku')
```

Now how can I insert A.ID and A.post_modified_gmt in one table as name table_first and B.order_item_name, E.gui into other table as name table_second in another database in same server
its important to prevent inserting duplicate data

Is it possible to group this statements as one, or two query?

Comment: *I want to insert selected data into 2 tables in other database* Does this "another database" is served by the same MySQL server instance?

Comment: yes , another database is in same MySQL server

Comment: If so I do not see the problem. Full specification for a table is `databasename.tablename`, for a column it is `databasename.tablename.columnname` respectively. So `INSERT INTO db2.table2 SELECT * FROM db1.table1` is a norma.